# How to debug node + mongo connection errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting random connections error from my node application to a mongodb server. The node application and the mongodb database are on separate machines. It works most of the time but *usually* fails when there are a lot of queries.

When that happens I can still run the mongo shell from the mongodb machine. And if I restart the node application, all is well again.

I couldn't seen anything meaningful in the application log, the mongo log and the system log that leads me to some conclusion.

I am suspecting something on the client machine side, but I couldn't find anything that made sense.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: What (driver) are you using to communicate with Mongo?  The node-mongodb-native driver supports passing a logger (with doDebug flag) to Db().  It will then output Connection debug information.  e.g. see https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js#L64

Comment: i am using the latest driver - thanks i hadn't seen that debug option. this should set me in the right direction it seems. I would accept your answer if you made it into one… I don't think I can accept a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the node-mongodb-native driver you can supply a logger with a doDebug=true flag to Db() and Connection().  It should then output debug information (to Console or whatever depending).  [This code, for example, appears to output some Connection debug information](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js#L64)